# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused

Tags: r

I'm developing an R package, which contains the following function:

```
#' @export
makeEnvironment = function(name) {
  envir = R6::R6Class(
    public = list(
      initialize = function(name) {
        remote.base = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
        private$client = gym::create_GymClient(remote.base)
        private$instance.id = gym::env_create(private$client, name)
        outdir = "/tmp/random-agent-results"
        gym::env_monitor_start(private$client, private$instance.id, outdir, 
          force = TRUE, resume = FALSE)
        print(gym::env_action_space_info(private$client, private$instance.id))
      }
    ),
    private = list(
      client = NULL,
      instance.id = NULL
    )
  )
  package.path = system.file(package = "reinforcelearn")
  path2pythonfile = paste0(package.path, "/gym_http_server.py")
  system2("python", args = path2pythonfile, stdout = NULL, wait = FALSE)
  envir$new(name)
}
```

The python script I call can be found here: https://github.com/openai/gym-http-api/blob/master/gym_http_server.py

When I start RStudio, load the package and run `makeEnvironment("MountainCar-v0")` I get the error

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Failed to
>   connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused

which is caused by `gym::env_create(private$client, name)`. If I just repeat `makeEnvironment("MountainCar-v0")` again, it works fine.

Can someone help? Why do I get this error and how to fix this?

Session Info

> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 [4]
>   LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] reinforcelearn_0.0.0.9070
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] httr_1.2.1
>   compiler_3.4.1   backports_1.1.0  R6_2.2.2         Matrix_1.2-10
>   tools_3.4.1       [7] nnet_7.3-12      curl_2.8.1
>   MDPtoolbox_4.0.3 grid_3.4.1       checkmate_1.8.3  jsonlite_1.5
>   [13] gym_0.1.0        linprog_0.9-2    lattice_0.20-35